# When there are duplicate values, how to return only one value from (loc)?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image: there are two maxium values in the file i'm working on. The problem is that i want (DeforAtMax) to have only a single value, not both of them. how can i solve this problem?]

I tried to get only one value using (loc) but it takes all possible values. How to return only one value?

Comment: ```print(df.loc[MaxLoad, "Deformation [mm]"][0])```

Comment: @Kkameleon answer gives you the first value, from left to right (`15.57212` in your screenshot). This may be of interest to you: https://www.askpython.com/python/list/indexing-in-python

Answer (score 1):

@kkameleon has the right answer if you only want the first value. So you could modify that with `.sort_values()` to get the smallest or largest either.

With your force/deformation data, you might want the average of the values, so use

```
DeforAtMax.mean()
```

That'll give you a single value which is the average of the deformations.